# How to evaluate string in groovy

Tags: groovy, evaluate

I have following string:

```
data = ["myKey": "myValue"]
```

and want to evaluate it as map:

```
def map = evaluate(data)
```

Looks like I'm doing something wrong but I get

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: DUMMY.evaluate() is

 applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [["myKey": "myValue"]]
```

So my question is how to perform such evaluation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a `String` like so:

```
data = '["myKey": "myValue"]'
```

If that is the case, you can evaluate it to a `Map` by using the [`Eval`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html) class

```
map = Eval.me( data )
```